# jQuery / JavaScript code not working on iPhones

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone

I have been trying this code for a webpage preloader and it works well on all devices except iPhone.
The code is for a loading bar and at 100% it should fade out, but on iPhones it just gets stuck and never fades out.


Can anyone help me figure out why?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var progress = 0;
            document.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(document.readyState == "interactive") {
                    var allElement = $("*");
                    var length = allElement.length;
                    for( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                        set_element(allElement[i], length);
                    }
                }
            }
        function set_element(element, totalElement) {
            var percentage = 100 / totalElement;
            if($(element).length == 1) {
                $("#fill").animate({ width:progress+percentage+"%" }, 200, function() {
                    if(document.getElementById("fill").style.width=="100%") {
                        $(".main").fadeOut(1200);
                    }
                });
                progress = progress + percentage;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It's probably due to floating point roundoff error.

Answer (score 1):

The probably is most likely due to floating point inaccuracy, so when you add up all the percentages, it ends up being something like 99.999999% or 100.0000001%, not exactly 100%.

You should pass both `i` and `length` to `set_element`, then it can calculate the percentage directly, rather than incrementing the global variable.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    var allElement = $("*");
    var length = allElement.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      set_element(allElement[i], length, i);
    }
  }
}

function set_element(element, totalElement, curIndex) {
  var percentage = 100  * (curIndex / totalElement);
  if ($(element).length == 1) {
    $("#fill").animate({
      width: percentage + "%"
    }, 200, function() {
      if (document.getElementById("fill").style.width == "100%") {
        $(".main").fadeOut(1200);
      }
    });
    progress = progress + percentage;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Unfortunately, this code breaks the loading bar altogether and it doesn't transition on any device, whereas before the problem was only on iPhones.

From what I've read, it seems like the problem lies with the fadeOut effect, it seems like it is not supported on iPhone? I still don't know how to fix that thought.

Comment: It seems hard to imagine such a common operation wouldn't work.